What wait types would terrible RCSI performance cause?
Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) is well-understood. The key way that it can cause performance bottlenecks is if the version chains get too long. Are there any wait type that indicate this specific issue? Or is it only shown by other wait types (and if so, what?).


The key way that it can cause performance bottlenecks is if the version chains get too long.

This isn't usually as much of a problem with RCSI as with SI. Statement snapshots for RCSI tend to be more recent by their nature. That said, it can still happen with long-running RCSI statements.
A major cost of RCSI is the extra admin work and storage. If you weren't already using versions for another purpose (like online index builds), the additional 14 bytes per row is a cost that every update and delete (and some inserts) must bear. This can also cause mid-page splits (or forwarded records for heaps), which are relatively expensive to perform and log.
In any case, generating and cleaning up versions isn't free. Some fraction of your server's capabilities are now dedicated to admin work. Naturally, there are many benefits to RCSI as well but you aren't asking about those.
Assuming your tempdb isn't already struggling, or close to being so, the effects in that area are often overstated.

Are there any wait type that indicate this specific issue?

No. Locating the right version may be admin work, but it's still active work—the server isn't waiting for any resource to become available.
Queries traversing long chains may be slower—perhaps seriously so—but this mostly shows up as increased CPU consumption. You might see higher SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 'waits' but these are not directly attributable to version chain traversal.
There are DMVs and performance counters you can monitor for excessive version store use and chain length. Wait statistics are for monitoring waits, not a pancea for diagnosing all inefficiencies.

Adding to Paul's answer: A way to monitor tempdb version store getting out of hand is by using PerfMon counters

\SQLServer:Transactions\Version Store Size (KB)
\SQLServer:Transactions\Longest Transaction Running Time

They are usually related -  the version store cannot clear as long as there is an open transaction that could potentially access the data.
